# Saber el mínimo de de un vector con punteros con tamaño n

Tags: c, punteros

Salta este error:

> warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void  //**’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
>        scanf("%p", vector[i] );

Este es mi código:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>



int main() {

int *vector;
int tam=0;
int minimo=10000;

  printf("Introduce una longitud del array:\n" );
  scanf("%i", &tam);

  vector=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*tam);

for (int i = 0; i <=tam; i++) {
  printf("Introduce un valor para posicion %i\n",i );
  scanf("%p", vector[i] );
}

  //hayamos minimo

for (int j = 0; j <= tam; j++) {

  if (vector[j]<minimo) {
    minimo=vector[j];
  }

}

  printf("%i", minimo );

  free(vector);


return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es pedir un entero; la expresión `vector[i]` es equivalente a `*( vector + i )`, de ahí el aviso del compilador; en lugar de un puntero, estás pasando un entero.

Cambia tu código a

```
printf("Introduce un valor para posicion %i\n",i );
scanf("%p", &( vector[i] ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

> El formato% p requiere un argumento de tipo void *. Si los punteros de tipo int * e int (*) [10] tienen la misma representación que void * y se pasan como argumentos de la misma manera, como es el caso para la mayoría de las implementaciones, es probable que funcione, pero no está garantizado. Debería convertir explícitamente los punteros a void *

Revisa este hilo. Fuente: [print the memory location of a variable (or pointer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374880/print-the-memory-location-of-a-variable-or-pointer)